# Crash when reading from console - masm32

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I created a masm program called t.exe which suppose to read input from cmd and output it.
I know they may be another methods to do it but i want to make it using `Readconsole

`Here is the code:

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

STD_INPUT_HANDLE EQU -10 

.data?
ByteAry dd 8 dup (?)
var dd ?
.code 
start: 
invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
invoke ReadConsole,eax,offset ByteAry,sizeof ByteAry,offset var,0
invoke StdOut,ByteAry
invoke ExitProcess,0 
end start
```

I try to run it but i got a Microsoft error and the program exits ("*t.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience*"). 
Actually if anyone know a good book to start with masm... I need it as I struggle with data types and please no offensive comments :)

Comment: +0.49 just for not bothering with the 16-bit crap.  Someone realizes it's the 21st century.  :)  You really need to add the error message to your post, though.

Comment: C:\masm32>t.exe hello


C:\masm32>
t.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: i want when i type t.exe hello
it will output hello again but unfortuanlly i got the error above

Comment: And where is this `StdOut` function defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your code using WinAPI functions ReadConsole and WriteConsole:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall

option casemap:none

include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc

includeLib kernel32.lib

.data

.data?
consoleOutHandle dd ?
consoleInHandle dd ?
bytearray db 32 dup(?)
ReadWritten dd ? 

.code

start:
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle

mov consoleOutHandle, eax

push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle

mov consoleInHandle, eax

push 0
push offset ReadWritten
push sizeof bytearray
push offset bytearray
push consoleInHandle
call ReadConsole

push 0
push offset ReadWritten
push sizeof bytearray
push offset bytearray
push consoleOutHandle
call WriteConsole

push 0
call ExitProcess

end start
```